# Are there any tutorials for putting an app on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have my app fully deployed for free at https://blooming-summer-8571.herokuapp.com/ but want to start paying for hosting for my own custom domain. I have also bought a domain name that I want to put my app on. What are the best resources or even google search key words that will help me do this through heroku?

Comment: Note that do you not have to pay to *attach* an existing custom domain on Heroku. You just have to modify your DNS (if you have DNS hosting; many hosts include it with registration) or you can use the Zerigo DNS add-on (https://addons.heroku.com/zerigo_dns) if you need your DNS hosted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to go through the heroku dev center located at:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/

There are topics from the very basics to more advanced ones. You're looking for the custom domain setup, instructions for which can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains